# マクロでリスト作成について

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorを使って以下のようなリストファイル作成がしたいです。
上記のようなフォルダに対してアドレスをコピーすると上のようなリストがEmEditorで作成できる仕組みです。

事例
G:\鈴木家の動画

このようなフォルダがあったときに"鈴木家の動画"のアドレスをコピーするとフォルダのリストを生成して"鈴木家の動画"という同じフォルダにリストを作ってEmEditorで開いて表示してくれる仕組みです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: お手数ですがご質問をサンプルや画面図などを使い明確化してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。サンプル画像を出しました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Windows のバッチファイルで十分実現できそうな内容ですが、**テキストエディタ** のマクロで実行しようとしているのはなぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のようにマクロを書いてください。

**ListDir.jsee**

```
var sFolder = "G:\\鈴木家の動画";  // ここにフォルダをコピーする
document.writeln( sFolder );

var today = new Date();
document.writeln( "リスト作成時  " + today );
document.writeln( "" );

var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var Folder = FSO.GetFolder(sFolder);
var FileCollection = Folder.Files;

for(var objEnum = new Enumerator(FileCollection); !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext()) {
    f = objEnum.item();
    sText = FSO.GetFileName( f ) + "  更新日時 " + f.DateLastModified + " 作成日時 " + f.DateCreated + " サイズ " + f.size + " バイト";
    document.writeln( sText );
}
```

参考: [Use JScript or JavaScript to traverse through a collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/use-jscript-javascript-traverse-collection)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。